# How get data from Material UI TextField, DropDownMenu components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I created a form, I have several TextField, DropDownMenu Material UI components included, question is how I can collect all data from all TextFields, DropDownMenus in one obj and sent it to the server. For TextField it has TextField.getValue() Returns the value of the input. But I can`t understand how to use it.

```
var React = require('react'),
    mui = require('material-ui'),
    Paper = mui.Paper,
    Toolbar = mui.Toolbar,
    ToolbarGroup = mui.ToolbarGroup,
    DropDownMenu = mui.DropDownMenu,
    TextField = mui.TextField,
    FlatButton = mui.FlatButton,
    Snackbar = mui.Snackbar;

var menuItemsIwant = [
  { payload: '1', text: '[Select a finacial purpose]' },
  { payload: '2', text: 'Every Night' },
  { payload: '3', text: 'Weeknights' },
  { payload: '4', text: 'Weekends' },
  { payload: '5', text: 'Weekly' }
];
var menuItemsIcan = [
  { payload: '1', text: '[Select an objective]' },
  { payload: '2', text: 'Every Night' },
  { payload: '3', text: 'Weeknights' },
  { payload: '4', text: 'Weekends' },
  { payload: '5', text: 'Weekly' }
];
var menuItemsHousing = [
  { payload: '1', text: '[Select housing]' },
  { payload: '2', text: 'Every Night' },
  { payload: '3', text: 'Weeknights' },
  { payload: '4', text: 'Weekends' },
  { payload: '5', text: 'Weekly' }
];
var menuItemsIlive = [
  { payload: '1', text: '[Select family mambers]' },
  { payload: '2', text: 'Every Night' },
  { payload: '3', text: 'Weeknights' },
  { payload: '4', text: 'Weekends' },
  { payload: '5', text: 'Weekly' }
];
var menuItemsLifestyle = [
  { payload: '1', text: '[Select lifestyle]' },
  { payload: '2', text: 'Every Night' },
  { payload: '3', text: 'Weeknights' },
  { payload: '4', text: 'Weekends' },
  { payload: '5', text: 'Weekly' }
];
var menuItemsLifestyle2 = [
  { payload: '1', text: '[Select savings]' },
  { payload: '2', text: 'Every Night' },
  { payload: '3', text: 'Weeknights' },
  { payload: '4', text: 'Weekends' },
  { payload: '5', text: 'Weekly' }
];
var menuItemsIncome = [
  { payload: '1', text: '[Select your yearly income]' },
  { payload: '2', text: 'Every Night' },
  { payload: '3', text: 'Weeknights' },
  { payload: '4', text: 'Weekends' },
  { payload: '5', text: 'Weekly' }
];
var Content = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      //formData: {
      //  name: '',
      //  age: '',
      //  city: '',
      //  state: ''
      //},
      errorTextName: '',
      errorTextAge: '',
      errorTextCity: '',
      errorTextState: ''
    };
  },

  render: function() {

    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row color-bg"></div>
        <div className="row main-bg">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="mui-app-content-canvas page-with-nav">
              <div className="page-with-nav-content">

                <Paper zDepth={1}>

                  <h2 className="title-h2">Now, what would you like to do?</h2>

                  <Toolbar>
                    <ToolbarGroup key={1} float="right">
                      <span>I want to</span>
                      <DropDownMenu
                        className="dropdown-long"
                        menuItems={menuItemsIwant}
                        //autoWidth={false}
                      />
                    </ToolbarGroup>
                  </Toolbar>

                  <div className="clearfix"></div>

                  <Toolbar>
                    <ToolbarGroup key={2} float="right">
                      <span>So I can</span>
                      <DropDownMenu
                        className="dropdown-long"
                        menuItems={menuItemsIcan}
                        //autoWidth={false}
                      />
                    </ToolbarGroup>
                  </Toolbar>

                  <h2 className="title-h2">Please, share a little about you.</h2>

                  <div className="clearfix"></div>

                  <Toolbar>
                    <ToolbarGroup key={3} float="right">
                      <span>I am</span>
                      <TextField
                        id="name"
                        className="text-field-long"
                        ref="textfield"
                        hintText="Full name"
                        errorText={this.state.errorTextName}
                        onChange={this._handleErrorInputChange}
                      />
                      <span>and I am</span>
                      <TextField
                        id="age"
                        className="text-field-short"
                        ref="textfield"
                        hintText="00"
                        errorText={this.state.errorTextAge}
                        onChange={this._handleErrorInputChange}
                      />
                      <span className="span-right-measure">years of age.</span>
                    </ToolbarGroup>
                  </Toolbar>

                  <div className="clearfix"></div>

                  <Toolbar>
                    <ToolbarGroup key={4} float="right">
                      <span>I</span>
                      <DropDownMenu
                        hintText="I"
                        menuItems={menuItemsHousing}
                        //autoWidth={false}
                      />
                      <span>in</span>
                      <TextField
                        id="city"
                        ref="textfield"
                        className="text-field-long"
                        hintText="City"
                        errorText={this.state.errorTextCity}
                        onChange={this._handleErrorInputChange}
                      />
                      <span>,</span>
                      <TextField
                        id="state"
                        ref="textfield"
                        className="text-field-short text-field-right-measure"
                        hintText="ST"
                        errorText={this.state.errorTextState}
                        onChange={this._handleErrorInputChange}
                      />
                    </ToolbarGroup>
                  </Toolbar>

                  <div className="clearfix"></div>

                  <Toolbar>
                    <ToolbarGroup key={5} float="right">
                      <span>Where I live</span>
                      <DropDownMenu
                        className="dropdown-long"
                        menuItems={menuItemsIlive}
                        //autoWidth={false}
                      />
                    </ToolbarGroup>
                  </Toolbar>

                  <div className="clearfix"></div>

                  <Toolbar>
                    <ToolbarGroup key={6} float="right">
                      <span>My lifestyle is</span>
                      <DropDownMenu
                        className="dropdown-short"
                        menuItems={menuItemsLifestyle}
                        //autoWidth={false}
                      />
                      <span>and I've saved</span>
                      <DropDownMenu
                        className="dropdown-short"
                        menuItems={menuItemsLifestyle2}
                        //autoWidth={false}
                      />
                    </ToolbarGroup>
                  </Toolbar>

                  <div className="clearfix"></div>

                  <Toolbar>
                    <ToolbarGroup key={7} float="right">
                      <span>My yearly household is about</span>
                      <DropDownMenu
                        className="dropdown-mobile"
                        menuItems={menuItemsIncome}
                        //autoWidth={false}
                      />
                    </ToolbarGroup>
                  </Toolbar>

                  <div className="clearfix"></div>

                  <div className="button-place">
                    <FlatButton
                      onTouchTap={this._handleClick}
                      label="I'm done lets go!"
                    />

                    <Snackbar
                      ref="snackbar"
                      message="Invalid input, please check and try again"
                    />
                  </div>

                </Paper>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },

  _handleErrorInputChange: function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === 'name') {
      var name = e.target.value;
      this.setState({
        //name: name,
        errorTextName: e.target.value ? '' : 'Please, type your Name'
      });
    } else if (e.target.id === 'age') {
      var age = e.target.value;
      this.setState({
        //age: age,
        errorTextAge: e.target.value ? '' : 'Check Age'
      });
    } else if (e.target.id === 'city') {
      var city = e.target.value;
      this.setState({
        //city: city,
        errorTextCity: e.target.value ? '' : 'Type City'
      });
    } else if (e.target.id === 'state') {
      var state = e.target.value;
      this.setState({
        //state: state,
        errorTextState: e.target.value ? '' : 'Type State'
      });
    }
  },

  _handleClick: function(e) {
    this.refs.snackbar.show();
    //TODO: find a way to change errorText for all empty TextField
    if (this.refs.textfield && this.refs.textfield.getValue().length === 0) {
      this.setState({
        errorTextState: 'Type State',
        errorTextCity: 'Type City',
        errorTextAge: 'Check Age',
        errorTextName: 'Please, type your Name'
      });
    }
  }

});

module.exports = Content;
```

I want to send it on a server in the _handleClick method.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Add an `onChange` handler to each of your `TextField` and `DropDownMenu` elements. When it is called, save the new value of these inputs in the `state` of your `Content` component. In render, retrieve these values from `state` and pass them as the `value` prop. See [Controlled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

```
var Content = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            textFieldValue: ''
        };
    },

    _handleTextFieldChange: function(e) {
        this.setState({
            textFieldValue: e.target.value
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TextField value={this.state.textFieldValue} onChange={this._handleTextFieldChange} />
            </div>
        )
    }

});
```

Now all you have to do in your `_handleClick` method is retrieve the values of all your inputs from `this.state` and send them to the server.

You can also use the `React.addons.LinkedStateMixin` to make this process easier. See [Two-Way Binding Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html). The previous code becomes:

```
var Content = React.createClass({

    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            textFieldValue: ''
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TextField valueLink={this.linkState('textFieldValue')} />
            </div>
        )
    }

});
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the `onChange` handler for the DropDownMenu component will get called with the following arguments: _event_, _key_, _payload_. Payload is the selected `MenuItem`'s value. Key is the `MenuItem`'s index. See the source: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/DropDownMenu/DropDownMenu.jsx

Comment: Quoting react documentation : ReactLink is deprecated as of React v15. The recommendation is to explicitly set the value and change handler, instead of using ReactLink.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html

Comment: why the underscore in _handleTextFieldChange?

Comment: @Mr.White Just a stylistic convention, as we'd consider that method to be private, i.e. it would not make sense to call it from outside of that component's context. I do not personally enforce this convention, I just reused the code sample from Vitalii's question.

Comment: When a user is typing characters one by one, onChange event is fired and call setState to update value, Then render is called, again and again, So when typing user feels slowness and stuck of typing. how to avoid this sort of situation?

Answer (score 29):

Here all solutions are based on Class Component, 
but i guess most of the people who learned React recently (like me), 
at this time using functional Component.
So here is the solution based on functional component.

Using useRef hooks of ReactJs and inputRef property of TextField.

```
    import React, { useRef, Component } from 'react'
    import { TextField, Button } from '@material-ui/core'
    import SendIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Send'

    export default function MultilineTextFields() {
    const valueRef = useRef('') //creating a refernce for TextField Component

    const sendValue = () => {
        return console.log(valueRef.current.value) //on clicking button accesing current value of TextField and outputing it to console 
    }

    return (
        <form noValidate autoComplete='off'>
        <div>
            <TextField
            id='outlined-textarea'
            label='Content'
            placeholder='Write your thoughts'
            multiline
            variant='outlined'
            rows={20}
            inputRef={valueRef}   //connecting inputRef property of TextField to the valueRef
            />
            <Button
            variant='contained'
            color='primary'
            size='small'
            endIcon={<SendIcon />}
            onClick={sendValue}
            >
            Send
            </Button>
        </div>
        </form>
    )
    }
```

Comment: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: You don't need to import `Component` from React if you're using functional components.

Comment: This only worked for me, if used an empty constructor for `useRef()`. No empty string.

Comment: Thank you, I was using `ref` instead of `inputRef`

Answer (score 13):

Try this,

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';

import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const Input = () => {
    const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState('');

    const handleTextInputChange = event => {
        setTextInput(event.target.value);
    };
    
    return(
        <TextField
            label="Text Input"
            value= {textInput}
            onChange= {handleTextInputChange}
        />
    );
}

export default Input;
```

Explanation if the above code was not clear.

First we create a state to store the text input called **textInput** and assign it the value ''.

Then we return a material UI `<TextField />` component whose **value** attribute is set to the **textInput** state. Doing this we display the current value of the **textInput** in the `<TextField />`. Any changes to the value of **textInput** will change the **value** attribute of the `<TextField />`, courtesy of React.

Then we use the **onChange** attribute of `<TextField />` to run a handler function every time the value of the `<TextField />` **value** attribute changes. This handler function is an arrow function stored in the constant **handleTextInputChange**. It takes an **event** as an argument. When the **onChange** attribute runs the handler function, it sends the **event** as an argument to the handler function.

The value of the `<TextField />` is stored in **event.target.value**. We then use the **setTextInput** method of the state to set the state to the **value** attribute of the `<TextField />`. Thus this change is reflected in the `<TextField />` whose **value** attribute is the value of the **textInput** state.

Thus the data input into the `<TextField />` is stored in the state **textInput**, ready to be used when required.

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your solution?

Comment: @SemihArslanoğlu I have added an explanation to my solution. I hope you find it comprehensible.

Comment: This slow down on Phone like Samsung A30 or same hardware.

Answer (score 7):

**In 2020 for TextField, via functional components:**

```
const Content = () => {
   ... 
      const textFieldRef = useRef();

      const readTextFieldValue = () => {
        console.log(textFieldRef.current.value)
      }
   ...
  
      return(
       ...
       <TextField
        id="myTextField"
        label="Text Field"
        variant="outlined"
        inputRef={textFieldRef}
       />
       ...
      )

}
```

Note that this isn't complete code.

Answer (score 6):

flson's code did not work for me. For those in the similar situation, here is my slightly different code:

`<TextField ref='myTextField'/>`

get its value using

`this.refs.myTextField.input.value`

Answer (score 6):

The strategy of the accepted answer is correct, but here's a generalized example that works with the current version of React and Material-UI.

The flow of data should be one-way:

- the initialState is initialized in the constructor of the MyForm control
- the `TextArea`s are populated from this initial state
- changes to the TextAreas are propagated to the `state` via the `handleChange` callback.
- the `state` is accessed from the `onClick` callback---right now it just writes to the console.  If you want to add validation it could go there.

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "material-ui/TextField";
import RaisedButton from "material-ui/RaisedButton";

const initialState = {
    error: null, // you could put error messages here if you wanted
    person: {
        firstname: "",
        lastname: ""
    }
};

export class MyForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = initialState;
        // make sure the "this" variable keeps its scope
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.state.error}</div>
                <div>
                    <TextField
                        name="firstname"
                        value={this.state.person.firstname}
                        floatingLabelText="First Name"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <TextField
                        name="lastname"
                        value={this.state.person.lastname}
                        floatingLabelText="Last Name"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <RaisedButton onClick={this.onClick} label="Submit!" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    onClick() {
        console.log("when clicking, the form data is:");
        console.log(this.state.person);
    }

    handleChange(event, newValue): void {
        event.persist(); // allow native event access (see: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html)
        // give react a function to set the state asynchronously.
        // here it's using the "name" value set on the TextField
        // to set state.person.[firstname|lastname].            
        this.setState((state) => state.person[event.target.name] = newValue);

    }

}


React.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

(Note: You may want to write one `handleChange` callback per MUI Component to eliminate that ugly `event.persist()` call.)

Answer (score 5):

Faced to this issue after a long time since question asked here. when checking material-ui code I found it's now accessible through `inputRef` property.

```
...
<CssTextField
  inputRef={(c) => {this.myRefs.username = c}}
  label="Username"
  placeholder="xxxxxxx"
  margin="normal"
  className={classes.textField}
  variant="outlined"
  fullWidth
/>
...
```

Then Access value like this.

```
  onSaveUser = () => {
    console.log('Saving user');
    console.log(this.myRefs.username.value);
  }
```

Comment: I think this needs to be the accepted answer in 2020

Answer (score 4):

Here's the simplest solution i came up with, we get the value of the input created by material-ui textField :

```
      create(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let name = this.refs.name.input.value;
        alert(name);
      }

      constructor(){
        super();
        this.create = this.create.bind(this);
      }

      render() {
        return (
              <form>
                <TextField ref="name" hintText="" floatingLabelText="Your name" /><br/>
                <RaisedButton label="Create" onClick={this.create} primary={true} />
              </form>
        )}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about y'all but for my own lazy purposes I just got the text fields from 'document' by ID and set the values as parameters to my back-end JS function:

```js
//index.js

      <TextField
        id="field1"
        ...
      />

      <TextField
        id="field2"
        ...
      />

      <Button
      ...
      onClick={() => { printIt(document.getElementById('field1').value,
      document.getElementById('field2').value)    
      }}>


//printIt.js

export function printIt(text1, text2) {
console.log('on button clicked');
alert(text1);
alert(text2);
};
```

It works just fine.

Comment: This is an example of an uncontrolled component, which is fine, but not recommended according to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Content extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TextField ref={(input) => this.input = input} />
        );
    }

    _doSomethingWithData() {
        let inputValue =  this.input.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this, where should they put it? What does it do? This answer isn't helpful without additional context?