# How to get text from textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to get the text from a textfield from material UI without using onChange? It just seems very weird that I would have to onChange keep track of the value then use that value when trying to do anything else.

Here is what I found and tried to use to answer my question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29792379/15868117

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Can you provide any code of yours? Is this editable `textfiled` or smth else maybe?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/2kfgPYf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

**Create a state that will track the input change as follows**

```js
import {useState} from 'react'
...

const [value, setValue] = useState("")
```

**Then**:

```
<div>
<TextField 
...
value={value}
onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
/>

<p>You typed: {value}<p>
</div>
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm confused by the syntax but that's just because I am new to react. At a glance, this looks fine even though it uses onChange. I will do some more research into useState. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like `onChange` for some reason, you can use other events, like `onBlur` for example.

> The onblur event occurs when an object loses focus.

Another approach is to use `onChange` combined with `debounce`, if you are sending search query to backend, setting 0.5s/1s debounce will prevent sending too many request in short time.